# opencv android: calling different methods after initialization

Tags: android, opencv

I have a class with three different methods transforming images using OpenCV. I init OpenCV with the following mechanism:

```
public void load() {
    // init opencv (see also mLoaderCallback below)
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, a, mLoaderCallback);
}

// callback function when OpenCVLoader.initAsync is finished
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(a) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                // position 1

                // test opencvImageTransformation1()
                opencvImageTransformation1();

                // test opencvImageTransformation3()
                opencvImageTransformation3();

            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

public void opencvImageTransformation1() {
    // do something
}

public void opencvImageTransformation2() {
    // do something
}

public void opencvImageTransformation3() {
    // do something
}
```

In the first step of developing my application, I called all the methods from "position 1" (see code above). This was enough for testing, but now I need to call the opencv methods at different points in time from my application. But how do I do this?

One basic option would be to call initAsync from all three methods and have three different callback functions, each performing one of the image transformations at their "position 1". But this would be not very efficient, since I had to repeat the initialization three time when I only need it once, right?

But if I initialized first and then called the transformation methods from outside, I would have to make sure that the initialization is done before the transformation operations run. I could use something like an infinite loop at the beginning of my methods checking if a certain flag is already set by the initialization callback method.

Still I think there must be a better way to accomplish what I need. How would you do it? Is there any recommended standard?

Answer (score 0):

well, you definitely have to wait, until the opencv so's loaded, your 'position 1' is indeed the 1st valid entry point for that.

but ofc, you can do that later, too, e.g. here:

```
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {}
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {}
```

Comment: ok, I think you did not get my question. some more details: say I have an activity with two buttons. when the user presses a button, an image from the file system shall be transformed using opencv functions. when he presses the next button the image shall be transformed in a different way. I can init opencv as soon as the activity starts. i could wait for the UI to build until opencv is ready, but ofc I would unnecessarily delay the UI. but if I show the UI before opencv is ready, how do I make sure opencv has been initialized when the user presses the button?

Comment: in that case, your question was unclear. in any case, you can not do anything opencv related, until the so's got loaded, and no, calling initAsync multiple times is not a valid option.

Comment: so which would you prefer: a) hide the UI and call to show it from position 1 in the callback? or b) implement the waiting in the methods called by pressing one of the buttons (using some form of infinite loop?)

Comment: a) sounds easier to do